# Displaying age of contact on birthday calendar events

Tags: calendar

When entering birthdays on a Galaxy Ace S8530i (e.g. Tim 1993), how can I get the calendar to show Tim 1993 20 where the 20 on the end is Tim's age?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please try to improve the
quality of your question. [Some good hints how to ask questions can be
found on Meta](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/a/1182/). This
will also increase your chances to get a good answer.

Comment: Question seems clear enough to me, when OP enters a contacts birthday how can he get it to show how old the contact is on the calender reminder, is that correct?

Comment: @Sapper, for you to know, you cannot show the *age* in your (stock) calendar. But automatic addition of event for birthdays is possible. See the anwer.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, remember that you can only do this with your birthdays and events that are in your *google account* contacts. *NOT* phone contacts.

1. Go to google.com/calendar from a computer.
2. Under Other calendars in the left pane, click add.
3. Click `Browse interesting calendars`
4. Click `More` (the More next to Sports).
5. On Contacts' birthdays and events, click subscribe.
6. Sync your contacts and calendar with your google account.

After sucessful syncing, the events should appear in your handsets calendar.

If you need to add the event details of your **phone contacts**, you need to export your phone contacts to your google account (or to your Gmail)

<sup>See [this link](http://www.pctlc.com/tech-tips/Contacts-Birthdays-In-Google-Calendar.php) for more info</sup>

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: Automatically displaying the age of the contact in title of the event.

I remember Nokia non-smartphones doing this just fine anno 2002.